# keras image to array return dimension

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

For a color image of size 224 x 224, how come  image.img_to_array returns  (224, 224, 3) rather then (3, 224, 224)?

I was expecting that axis 0 and axis 1 would be a 2d array for a single color's intensity. What I believe I've got is a 2d array containing one row of each color.

Why is it all mixed up please?

Comment: I think you have your dimensions mixed up. You have a 2-D array of color values. Each of the 224x224 points gives you the RGB value for that point.

Another way to look at this is to open it up in an image editor. Each pixel is represented in that 224x224 array, and each pixel is made up of red, green and blue values.

Comment: doesn't  (224, 224, 3) mean 224 2d arrays of (224 x 3) ?

Comment: It's all the same, just from a different perspective. It can mean 224 2d arrays, or one 2d array (224x224) consisting of a list of values (the third dimension).

Think of how a printer or monitor works. http://www.visuacorp.com/post/understanding-a-pixel

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this by adding the argument data_format = "channels_first" so
img_to_array(img, data_format = "channels_first)

https://rdrr.io/cran/kerasR/man/img_to_array.html